# MPI.NET: run multiple sequential sessions

Tags: c#, .net, mpi, message-passing

I've been playing around with MPI.NET a little and I have come across an issue I can't seem to work around.

When creating tests for my code which runs MPI.NET, I have two unit tests which are run by MSTest sequentially, each of which creates a communicator and disposes it.
When doing this you end up in a situation where the communicator is both initialized and disposed in the second test (static variables are the cause here).

I'm not looking to solve this from a test perspective (running the tests differently won't solve the problem). 
I'm simply showing you that case in order to easily demonstrate the problem.

I'm hoping there is a sensible way to init MPI.NET twice, or somehow recycling it?

I did get in touch with the author of the project and he suggested I post here where someone more familiar with MPI itself might be able to help.

```
public static void RunMPIAction(Action<Intracommunicator> action)
{
    string[] args = null;
    using (var env = new Environment(ref args))
    {
        action(Communicator.world);
    }
}

MPI.Environment.RunMPIAction(comm =>
{
    this.Run(comm, logger, parameters);
}

MPI.Environment.RunMPIAction(comm => { int rank = comm.Rank; }, false);
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Added to the body of the post.  RunMPIAction can be called multiple times from different places, the actions shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Stevey, The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPI is not designed to be used like this. Creating new Environment calls [MPI_Init_thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473421(v=vs.85).aspx), which states:

> This function must be called by one thread only. That thread will be
>   known as the “Main Thread” and must be the same thread to call
>   MPI_Finalize.

Attempting to call it from multiple threads or from one thread multiple times will fail.

Disposing `Environment` calls [MPI_Finalize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473372(v=vs.85).aspx), which states:

> The MPI_Finalize function cleans up all state related to MPI. Once it
>   is called, no other MPI functions may be called, including MPI_Init
>   and MPI_Init_thread.

From that it should be clear that you have to have only one `Environment` per process, and you cannot recreate it once disposed.

So you have to refactor your code to take this into account. If you have some kind of reusable library - don't initialize MPI there (just check if it is initialized already and throw if not) and not finalize it there - only the "top-level" user of that library should do that. If you don't have reference to `Environment` instance that was created but you need to finalize environment, you can do it like this:

```
if (!MPI.Environment.Finalized)
    Unsafe.MPI_Finalize();
```

That's ok to do because `Environment` is semantically a singleton and could have been a static class, but because of convenient `using` statement was made non-static (with only instance member being `Dispose` function).